# JQuery Event Delegation Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am trying to make a click event listener that listens to a HTML event recently made. The whole selector thing is confusing me. Here is my code:

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slick").last().after("<div class='box'></div><div class='slick'></div>")
});

// With on():

$(".slick").on("click", function() {
    $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
.slick {
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 40px;
}
#button, #button1 {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div id="button">New Tab</div>
```

As you can see here the New Tab button adds two new elements exactly same to the ones that were there before. The only problem is that when I click the `.slick` element of the newly generated elements, the background color doesn't change like the first two `.slick` do.

> I do not want to have to put the elements inside of each other. Their tree order should stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `$(".slick").on("click", function() {...});` is **functionally identical** to `$(".slick").click(...)`. Remember that event binding is done at **runtime**, this means that the newly added `.slick` element does not have the click event bound to it. To ensure that you capture the click event from newly added elements, you have to rely on to event bubbling.

In other words, you want to listen to the click event bubbling up from *any* `.slick` element, at the level of a parent that is present at runtime. An example will be the document object:

```
$(document).on("click", ".slick", function() {
    $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

This code above basically does this: it instructs the `document` object to listen to a click event that has originated/bubbled up from any child element with the class of `slick`. Since the document object is already present at runtime, this will mean your callback is **always** fired, no matter at which time a new `.slick` element is added and clicked on.

Ideally, you do *not* want to bind that to the `document` object due to performance issue. Binding it to the closest parent that is available at runtime will do just as fine. Let's say all your `.slick` elements are added in a parent called `<div class="slick-wrapper">` that is present in the markup at runtime, then using `$('.slick-wrapper').on('click', '.slick', function() {...});` will also work.

Proof-of-concept:

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slick").last().after("<div class='box'></div><div class='slick'></div>")
});

$(document).on("click", ".slick", function() {
    $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
.slick {
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 40px;
}
#button, #button1 {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div id="button">New Tab</div>
```

Comment: @DiabloSteve You're welcome. I've updated my answer to explain why checking event bubbling on `document` is not an optimal solution, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style tag to affect future created elements. Something like this:

```js
var counter = 0;

$("#button").click(function() {
    $(".slick").last().after("<div class='box'></div><div class='slick'></div>")
});

// With on():

$(".slick").on("click", function() {
    $('<style>.box { background-color: blue !important; }</style>').appendTo('head'); 
});
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}
.slick {
  background-color: #B2B2B2;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 40px;
}
#button, #button1 {
  background-color: #BCBCBC;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slick"></div>
<div id="button">New Tab</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the "New Tab" button, js add new box and slick, the first 2 slick will change the color of all boxes, but the newer ones are not. The reason of this, you add event to the slick elements first, and after it you create a new one. 
This code will add event for the new ones as well:

```
$("body").on("click", ".slick", function() {
     $(".box").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```